# Do Compiler Template Implementations Introduce Circular Dependencies?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++11, circular-dependency

I am working on an API in C++ and trying /really/ hard not to use RTTI, (Run-Time Type Information), to implement some dependency injection functionality.

I believe I can do this, but by utilizing templates--but it got me wondering:

When the templates are "expanded" and implemented by the compiler, do they in fact introduce a circular dependency, (either compile time or run time), when the template class is implemented in a framework library, and the client of that class is in a upper tiered library?

Thanks for your help!

```
#include <string>

/************************************************************/
// Implemented in Framework.lib
namespace Framework 
{
    template<typename ShapeTemplateType>
    class Utility
    {           
        void Do()
        {
            ShapeTemplateType x;
            (void) x;
        }
    };
} // End namespace Framework 

/************************************************************/
// Implemented in Application.lib
namespace Application
{
    class StateObject
    {
        int i;
    };

    class Facade
    {
        Framework::Utility<StateObject> state;
    };
} // End Namespace Application


/********************************************************************/
// Implemented in Client
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    Application::Facade facade;

    //Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it does. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by your template is "implemented in Framework.lib"?  `template`s tend to be (barring some fancy dancing) is a pure header file construct.  In what way are they "implemented" in a particular lib?

Comment: @Yakk one of the answers below talks about the compilation unit, this is what I mean.

Comment: `Framework.lib` is almost certainly *not* the name of a compilation unit.  There are compilation units that are linked into `lib`s, but `lib`s are not compilation units.

Comment: @yak but those generated compilation units, whatever they are named, (.a), whatever, would still have a circular dependency, right?

Comment: @Pubby the code is simply there to illustrate a scenario where I think template code is generated that must have circular dependencies.

Comment: No.  See @DarkFalcon's answer -- the code for the `template` is generated in the compilation unit where it is instantiated -- ie, where the parameters are passed to it.  `Framework::Utility<T>` in the above code is not an instantiated template, so it doesn't live in any `.lib` or `.a` or any compilation unit.  `Framework::Utility<StateObject>` is an instantiation of a `template`, and as such lives in some compilation unit (and thence maybe some `.lib`)

Comment: @Yakk  So, in the compilation unit for Framework::Utility<StateObject>, which is an instantiation of the template, there would be a circular dependency there, and not in general Framework.lib, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the template is generated in the compilation unit where it is instantiated. In your example, the resulting machine code will be in `Application.lib`.

Comment: Just to be sure I am clear, according to your answer, even when there is no physical separation of tiers, and only one generated compilation unit, the code in the generated compilation unit would be dependent on the calling code, and vice versa, right? There would still be a circular dependency, though in the generated compilation unit...

Comment: Perhaps you might say that, but why would it matter? Generally a compilation unit is the level at which you have to worry about circular dependencies. Anything within one compilation unit is not of concern because it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: I was   having an issue with a circular dependency that was generated, and ended up with a stack overflow.  There is a bug with the MS Nov 2012 C++ compiler with the new Variadic Template support, and it took me a while to narrow it down to a compiler issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean a circular template dependency like:

```
template<class T>
using A = B<T>;

template<class T>
using B = A<T>;

int main()
{
    A<int>;
}
```

This fails at the declaration of A, because B is not available, if you fwd declare it it complains its incomplete.

I don't think its possible to have a circular dependency in templates because a complete type must be available for every template parameter used for an instantiation to be made.  Given that, the chain of template instantiations must therefore be acyclic.